# Vuejs непрочитанные сообщения

Tags: vue.js

Как узнать, открыт ли у собеседника наш с ним диалог, чтобы не присваивать статус непрочитанное для сообщения, отправленного ему, если у него открыт этот же диалог?

```
if (this.dialogSelect > 0){
    window.Echo.private('chat.' + this.dialogSelect)
        .listen('DialogMessage',({data,user_id}) => {
            this.messages.push({
                avatar: this.userAuth.avatar,
                fullname: this.userAuth.fullname,
                user_id: this.userAuth.id,
                replay: data
            });
            $('.contact-list__items[data-id="'+this.dialogSelect+'"]').find('.typing').removeClass('active');
            $('.chat--messages__wrapper').scrollTop($('.chat--messages__wrapper').prop('scrollHeight'));
        })
        .listenForWhisper('typing', (e) => {
            console.log(e);
            $('.contact-list__items[data-id="'+this.dialogSelect+'"]').find('.typing').addClass('active');

            if (this.typingTimer) clearTimeout(this.typingTimer);

            this.typingTimer = setTimeout(() => {
                $('.contact-list__items[data-id="'+this.dialogSelect+'"]').find('.typing').removeClass('active');
            }, 2000);
        });
}
```